# Writing a sequence to denote number of matches

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

[image]

I am trying to write a sequence ($a_n$) to denote number of matches at the $n$th figure.

I wrote first few terms: $a_1=3\;,a_2=5\;,a_3=7\;,a_4=9\;,a_5=11\;,\color\red{a_6=12}\quad$ therefore :
$a_n=2n+1$ for $1\le n\le5$ continue this process: $a_7=14\;,a_8=16\;,a_9=18,\;\color\red{a_{10=}19}$. so $a_n=2n$ for $7\le n\le9$.

I realized the pattern: the difference between two consecutive term is $2$ but for $a_{4n+2}$ the difference is $1$. however I don't know how to write general term of sequence for this pattern.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that you're only adding matches to the right?  From your last figure, it's going to depend on whether you continue right/left or whether you head up/down

Comment: @epte I think it is adding matches to the right.

Comment: So, after a2, the amount you're adding on repeatedly is (2, 2, 2, 1)?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It seems very periodic.  Perhaps you can manipulate some sine waves to that purpose?  There's probably a couple different ways to do it, but I'm picturing a summation with some sin inside